# Simplify $\dfrac {\partial }{\partial b}\left( \sigma ^{2}\right) =0$ and $\dfrac {\partial }{\partial m}\left( \sigma ^{2}\right) =0$

Tags: calculus, statistics

Given $\sigma ^{2}=\sum ^{N}_{i=1}\left[ y_{i}-\left( mx_{i}+b\right) \right] ^{2}$
How to simplify 
$\dfrac {\partial }{\partial b}\left( \sigma ^{2}\right) =0$ and
$\dfrac {\partial }{\partial m}\left( \sigma ^{2}\right) =0$

I want to know the difference of del operator and differential operator.

Comment: $\sigma ^{2}=\sum y^{2}_{i}-2m\sum x_{i}y_{i}+2b\sum y_{i}+m^{2}\sum x^{2}_{i}+2mb\sum x_{i}+Nb^{2}$

Comment: Ok. So if you differentiate those terms with respect to $b$ and $m$, what happens? Note that the $\partial$-derivative means that all other variables are treated as constants.

Comment: Calling this thing $\sigma^2$ seems infelicitous since in standard usage that would be the population variance of the errors (not the residuals) whereas here it's the sum of squares of the residuals (not the errors).

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks for your guide. $m=\dfrac {N\left( \sum x_{i}y_{i}\right) -\sum x_{i}\sum y_{i}}{N\left( \sum x^{2}_{i}\right) -\left( \sum x_{i}\right) ^{2}}$ and $b=\dfrac {\left( \sum x^{2}_{i}\right) \left( \Sigma y_{i}\right) -\left( \sum x_{i}y_{i}\right) \left( \sum x_{i}\right) }{N\left( \sum x^{2}_{i}\right) -\left( \sum x_{i}\right) ^{2}}$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial b} \sigma^2 & = \sum_{i=1}^N (2[y_i-(mx_i+b)] \cdot (-1) ) \\[10pt]
\frac{\partial}{\partial m} \sigma^2 & = \sum_{i=1}^N (2[y_i-(mx_i+b)] \cdot (-x_i) )
\end{align}
The chain rule is used for both of these.

Both $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}$ and $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial m}$ are differential operators.